# Braintree Drop In UI Field Validation

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

In one step checkout, I have multiple payment methods for customers to choose from like Braintree, Bank Transfer etc. For allowing customers to choose from multiple methods, I must make Braintree Fields mandatory only when Braintree is choosen as payment method. Is there any way by which I can make braintree fields like credit card, cvv etc. non mandatory? 
 [image: One Step Checkout]
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think I misunderstood your original question. It seems that you want to be able to bypass Drop-ins form hijacking if the user selects Bank Transfer. I put together a little demo to illustrate how I would go about doing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myform" action="/" method="get">
    <label for="pay-with">Pay with card</label>
    <input id="pay-with-cc" type="radio" name="pay-with" value="cc">

    <div id="container" style="display: none;"></div>

    <label for="bank-transfer">Pay with Bank Transfer</label>
    <input id="pay-with-bank-transfer" type="radio" name="pay-with" value="bank-transfer">

    <input type="submit" value="Pay">
  </form>
  <!-- Include your JS here -->      
</body>
</html>
```

And then your JavaScript file, you could do something like this:

```
(function () {
  var dropinHasRendered = false;
  var form = document.forms[0];
  var dropinContainer = form.querySelector('#container');
  var payWithCCRadio = form.querySelector('input#pay-with-cc');
  var payWithBankTransferRadio = form.querySelector('input#pay-with-bank-transfer');

  function renderBraintreeDropIn() {
    dropinHasRendered = true;

    // Make sure to use your client token here
    braintree.setup(YOUR_TOKEN, 'dropin', {container: 'container'});
  }

  function showBraintree() {
    dropinContainer.style.display = 'block';

    if (!dropinHasRendered) {
      renderBraintreeDropIn();
    }
  }

  function hideBraintree() {
    dropinContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }

  payWithBankTransferRadio.addEventListener('change', hideBraintree);
  payWithCCRadio.addEventListener('change', showBraintree);

  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if (form['pay-with'].value === 'bank-transfer') {
      event.preventDefault();

      // This allows your to bypass Drop-in
      HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form);
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that doesn't answer my question. Well, I guess there is practically no workaround to make the card number and expiry date non-mandatory.

Comment: @Harit Kyle updated his answer with a really nice example. In the future, I suggest [getting in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).